# C#: comctl32.dll version 6 in debugger

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, winapi, taskdialog, comctl32

I'm using the [WindowsAPICodePack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) for TaskDialog. When I try to show the dialog it says that it needs to load version 6 of comctl32.dll. So I added version 6 to the app.manifest and tried running it. Still no luck. I went to the Debug folder and ran the program without Visual Studio and it works fine. I'm guessing that Visual Studio isn't using the manifest file... I was wondering if there was a way to make it do this.

Comment: Could we add the exact error message into the question so that Google leads here for it? This had the correct answer for me but I only found vague mentions of it in other threads and had to eventually search for "EnableThemingInScope" to get here. Here's the error messages for Google's crawlers: "TaskDialog feature needs to load version 6 of comctl32.dll but a different version is current loaded in memory" with inner exception "Unable to find an entry point named 'TaskDialogIndirect' in DLL 'Comctl32.dll'."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Robpol86, your code is throwing SEHExceptions, because the signatures for ActivateActCtx and DeactivateActCtx are not correct. You have to use `UIntPtr` instead of `uint` for the lpCookie.

Therefore, the correct code for EnableThemingInScope.cs would be:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
{
    /// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830033
    /// <devdoc>
    ///     This class is intended to use with the C# 'using' statement in
    ///     to activate an activation context for turning on visual theming at
    ///     the beginning of a scope, and have it automatically deactivated
    ///     when the scope is exited.
    /// </devdoc>

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal class EnableThemingInScope : IDisposable
    {
        // Private data
        private UIntPtr cookie;
        private static ACTCTX enableThemingActivationContext;
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2006:UseSafeHandleToEncapsulateNativeResources")]
        private static IntPtr hActCtx;
        private static bool contextCreationSucceeded = false;

        public EnableThemingInScope(bool enable)
        {
            cookie = UIntPtr.Zero;
            if (enable && OSFeature.Feature.IsPresent(OSFeature.Themes))
            {
                if (EnsureActivateContextCreated())
                {
                    if (!ActivateActCtx(hActCtx, out cookie))
                    {
                        // Be sure cookie always zero if activation failed
                        cookie = UIntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ~EnableThemingInScope()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose()
        {
            if (cookie != UIntPtr.Zero)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (DeactivateActCtx(0, cookie))
                    {
                        // deactivation succeeded...
                        cookie = UIntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                }
                catch (SEHException)
                {
                    //Hopefully solved this exception
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2002:DoNotLockOnObjectsWithWeakIdentity")]
        private static bool EnsureActivateContextCreated()
        {
            lock (typeof(EnableThemingInScope))
            {
                if (!contextCreationSucceeded)
                {
                    // Pull manifest from the .NET Framework install
                    // directory

                    string assemblyLoc = null;

                    FileIOPermission fiop = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
                    fiop.AllFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery;
                    fiop.Assert();
                    try
                    {
                        assemblyLoc = typeof(Object).Assembly.Location;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
                    }

                    string manifestLoc = null;
                    string installDir = null;
                    if (assemblyLoc != null)
                    {
                        installDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyLoc);
                        const string manifestName = "XPThemes.manifest";
                        manifestLoc = Path.Combine(installDir, manifestName);
                    }

                    if (manifestLoc != null && installDir != null)
                    {
                        enableThemingActivationContext = new ACTCTX();
                        enableThemingActivationContext.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ACTCTX));
                        enableThemingActivationContext.lpSource = manifestLoc;

                        // Set the lpAssemblyDirectory to the install
                        // directory to prevent Win32 Side by Side from
                        // looking for comctl32 in the application
                        // directory, which could cause a bogus dll to be
                        // placed there and open a security hole.
                        enableThemingActivationContext.lpAssemblyDirectory = installDir;
                        enableThemingActivationContext.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID;

                        // Note this will fail gracefully if file specified
                        // by manifestLoc doesn't exist.
                        hActCtx = CreateActCtx(ref enableThemingActivationContext);
                        contextCreationSucceeded = (hActCtx != new IntPtr(-1));
                    }
                }

                // If we return false, we'll try again on the next call into
                // EnsureActivateContextCreated(), which is fine.
                return contextCreationSucceeded;
            }
        }

        // All the pinvoke goo...
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private extern static IntPtr CreateActCtx(ref ACTCTX actctx);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private extern static bool ActivateActCtx(IntPtr hActCtx, out UIntPtr lpCookie);
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
        private extern static bool DeactivateActCtx(uint dwFlags, UIntPtr lpCookie);

        private const int ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID = 0x004;

        private struct ACTCTX
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public string lpSource;
            public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
            public ushort wLangId;
            public string lpAssemblyDirectory;
            public string lpResourceName;
            public string lpApplicationName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, this is the correct answer. No need to change manifest with this.

Comment: +1 For correct answer. For future reference I had a similar broken uint cookie implementation from this msdn knowledge base article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830033 just for clarity: I could create the scope but then I got an SEH Exception on DeactivateActCtx. further debugging revealed that it was error code 6, which is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE as the cookie could not be used to deactivate the context properly due its wrong type.

Comment: Thanks! I was having trouble with comctl32.dll when publishing ClickOnce, and this solved it

Answer (score 4):

I recently ran into this problem when debugging code with the TaskDialogDemo in the CodePack. This is how I kind of fixed it. The problem with using this is if I open two or three dialogs it throws an SEHException, which I haven't figured out how to fix. So buyer beware.

Add **Core\Interop\TaskDialogs\EnableThemingInScope.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs {
    /// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830033
    /// <devdoc>
    ///     This class is intended to use with the C# 'using' statement in
    ///     to activate an activation context for turning on visual theming at
    ///     the beginning of a scope, and have it automatically deactivated
    ///     when the scope is exited.
    /// </devdoc>

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal class EnableThemingInScope : IDisposable {
        // Private data
        private uint cookie;
        private static ACTCTX enableThemingActivationContext;
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2006:UseSafeHandleToEncapsulateNativeResources" )]
        private static IntPtr hActCtx;
        private static bool contextCreationSucceeded = false;

        public EnableThemingInScope( bool enable ) {
            cookie = 0;
            if ( enable && OSFeature.Feature.IsPresent( OSFeature.Themes ) ) {
                if ( EnsureActivateContextCreated() ) {
                    if ( !ActivateActCtx( hActCtx, out cookie ) ) {
                        // Be sure cookie always zero if activation failed
                        cookie = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ~EnableThemingInScope() {
            Dispose();
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() {
            Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize( this );
        }

        private void Dispose() {
            if ( cookie != 0 ) {
                try {
                    if ( DeactivateActCtx( 0, cookie ) ) {
                        // deactivation succeeded...
                        cookie = 0;
                    }
                } catch ( SEHException ) {
                    // Robpol86: I don't know how to fix this!
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Reliability", "CA2002:DoNotLockOnObjectsWithWeakIdentity" )]
        private static bool EnsureActivateContextCreated() {
            lock ( typeof( EnableThemingInScope ) ) {
                if ( !contextCreationSucceeded ) {
                    // Pull manifest from the .NET Framework install
                    // directory

                    string assemblyLoc = null;

                    FileIOPermission fiop = new FileIOPermission( PermissionState.None );
                    fiop.AllFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery;
                    fiop.Assert();
                    try {
                        assemblyLoc = typeof( Object ).Assembly.Location;
                    } finally {
                        CodeAccessPermission.RevertAssert();
                    }

                    string manifestLoc = null;
                    string installDir = null;
                    if ( assemblyLoc != null ) {
                        installDir = Path.GetDirectoryName( assemblyLoc );
                        const string manifestName = "XPThemes.manifest";
                        manifestLoc = Path.Combine( installDir, manifestName );
                    }

                    if ( manifestLoc != null && installDir != null ) {
                        enableThemingActivationContext = new ACTCTX();
                        enableThemingActivationContext.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( ACTCTX ) );
                        enableThemingActivationContext.lpSource = manifestLoc;

                        // Set the lpAssemblyDirectory to the install
                        // directory to prevent Win32 Side by Side from
                        // looking for comctl32 in the application
                        // directory, which could cause a bogus dll to be
                        // placed there and open a security hole.
                        enableThemingActivationContext.lpAssemblyDirectory = installDir;
                        enableThemingActivationContext.dwFlags = ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID;

                        // Note this will fail gracefully if file specified
                        // by manifestLoc doesn't exist.
                        hActCtx = CreateActCtx( ref enableThemingActivationContext );
                        contextCreationSucceeded = (hActCtx != new IntPtr( -1 ));
                    }
                }

                // If we return false, we'll try again on the next call into
                // EnsureActivateContextCreated(), which is fine.
                return contextCreationSucceeded;
            }
        }

        // All the pinvoke goo...
        [DllImport( "Kernel32.dll" )]
        private extern static IntPtr CreateActCtx( ref ACTCTX actctx );
        [DllImport( "Kernel32.dll" )]
        private extern static bool ActivateActCtx( IntPtr hActCtx, out uint lpCookie );
        [DllImport( "Kernel32.dll" )]
        private extern static bool DeactivateActCtx( uint dwFlags, uint lpCookie );

        private const int ACTCTX_FLAG_ASSEMBLY_DIRECTORY_VALID = 0x004;

        private struct ACTCTX {
            public int cbSize;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public string lpSource;
            public ushort wProcessorArchitecture;
            public ushort wLangId;
            public string lpAssemblyDirectory;
            public string lpResourceName;
            public string lpApplicationName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in **Core\Interop\TaskDialogs\NativeTaskDialog.cs** on line 93 (above *HResult hresult = TaskDialogNativeMethods.TaskDialogIndirect*) make the section look like this (in the end you will have three new lines):

```
// Here is the way we use "vanilla" P/Invoke to call TaskDialogIndirect().
HResult hresult;
using ( new EnableThemingInScope( true ) ) {
    hresult = TaskDialogNativeMethods.TaskDialogIndirect(
        nativeDialogConfig,
        out selectedButtonId,
        out selectedRadioButtonId,
        out checkBoxChecked );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This page describes how to add a custom manifest to your project in order to tell Windows to load the new  comctl32.dll (version 6.0):

- [Setting the correct manifest version](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Setting%20the%20correct%20manifest)

Does your manifest have the right dependency on comctl32.dll? Did you embed the created manifest?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Visual Studio in Debug mode. So far I haven't found a workaround, it works fine in Release mode.