# Windows API Code Pack TaskDialog missing icon

Tags: c#, windows, icons, windows-api-code-pack

The icons in my `TaskDialog` are missing:

[image]

And in the taskbar:
[image]

My code is this:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

...

TaskDialog taskDialog = new TaskDialog();
taskDialog.Caption = "Error";
taskDialog.InstructionText = "Test error message.";
taskDialog.Text = "Icon seems to be missing.";
taskDialog.DetailsExpandedText = "Test";
taskDialog.DetailsCollapsedLabel = "Expand";
taskDialog.StandardButtons = TaskDialogStandardButtons.Ok;
taskDialog.Icon = TaskDialogStandardIcon.Error;
taskDialog.Show();
```

I'm using version 1.1 from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4906).
Any clue why they are missing and how to enable them? Dependencies are set as following:

```
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this. Apparently it is a bug in the API itself.

```
taskDialog.Opened += new EventHandler(taskDialog_Opened);

...

public void taskDialog_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskDialog taskDialog = sender as TaskDialog;
    taskDialog.Icon = taskDialog.Icon;
    taskDialog.FooterIcon = taskDialog.FooterIcon;
    taskDialog.InstructionText = taskDialog.InstructionText;
}
```

Comment: how to do the same in vb.net?

Comment: `AddHandler taskDialog.Opened, Sub(sender As TaskDialog, args As EventArgs)
                                          sender.Icon = sender.Icon
                                          sender.InstructionText = sender.InstructionText
                                      End Sub`

Comment: Download WindowsAPICodePack by Aybe from NuGet to solve this issue. Works for me!

Comment: The `FooterIcon` line will only work, if the FooterText is set to something other than `null` or an empty string. +@csrowell

Comment: @KnorxThieus I wish you put the link in your comment.

Comment: This solution throws AccessViolationException

Comment: The solution for this is to use [WindowsAPICodePack](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1?utm_source=recordnotfound.com) by Aybe

Comment: I have to add, you seem to need to install v1.1.2 for this fix, which is [unfortunately kinda buggy](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1/issues/41).

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. The marked answer worked for me once I removed this line of code:

```
    taskDialog.FooterIcon = taskDialog.FooterIcon;
```

It was causing an unhandled exception.

Comment: Try `if (Icon != TaskDialogStandardIcon.None)
    Icon = Icon;
   if (FooterIcon != TaskDialogStandardIcon.None)
    FooterIcon = FooterIcon;`.

Comment: **PS:** If you have trouble with the right dialog window height, add then: `if (InstructionText != null)
 InstructionText = InstructionText;`. Hope that helped.